# The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly: Missing Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Updated my .NET Core SDK to the latest version (3.1.405) and now nothing works anymore.
Whenever I try `dotnet run` on any project I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.405\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(194,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\Test\Test.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.405\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(194,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\Test\Test.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.405\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(194,5): error MSB4018: File name: 'Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' [C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\Test\Test.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.405\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(194,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.FrameworkReferenceResolver.GetDefaultReferenceAssembliesPath() [C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\Test\Test.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.405\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(194,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateDepsFile.WriteDepsFile(String depsFilePath) [C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\Test\Test.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.405\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(194,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateDepsFile.ExecuteCore() [C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\Test\Test.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.405\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(194,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\Test\Test.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.405\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(194,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\Test\Test.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.405\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(194,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\Test\Test.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

Test.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

The error occurs on every single .NET Core project, even when creating a blank new one.

I've spent way too many hours looking for a solution and tried multiple solutions from similar threads, eg:

- Reinstalling SDK
- Downgrading to earlier SDK Version (3.1.x)
- Clearing NuGet Cache
- Calling `dotnet clean`
- Installing Mono 6.x
- Deleting `C:\Users\<UserName>\.nuget\packages`

My `dotnet --info` output:

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.102
 Commit:    71365b4d42

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19041
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.102\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.2
  Commit:  cb5f173b96

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.405 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

I feel like it might have to do with .NET 5 seemingly being the default. I've also read that `Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions` will no longer be supported with that version of the .NET SDK, but don't know what to do with that information and couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: i would try re-installing Visual Studio (or doing a repair) which should ensure the correct SDKs are there as well

Comment: I use VSCode for my .NET Core Projects. Nonetheless just tried repairing VS: took a while, but no success..

Comment: Deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders in each project may solve this issue

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: I had the same problem. The only thing that worked for me was to delete the sdk folders of 5.*. I've tried to uninstall them with the uninstall tool https://github.com/dotnet/cli-lab/releases but that version didn't show up.

Comment: Wow thank you, this finally fixed it. You're a lifesaver! How do I mark this as the solution?

Comment: I've added an answer that you can mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. The only thing that worked for me was to delete the sdk folders of 5.* (or move them to another location in case you need them again later).

I've tried to uninstall them with the uninstall tool github.com/dotnet/cli-lab/releases but that version didn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an issue where I had 7 projects in a solution. The ones that failed had their own assembly name, and the error indicated "Duplicate names".

Once change per example below the problem stopped.

```xml
Assembly Name (before) : SpecFlow
Assembly Name (after)  : Core.SpecFlow
//Where the core Assembly had already been built, which cause the "Duplicates" issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only thing that worked for me was to install the latest version of `Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions` package from by NuGet!

In your default project, just right click on Dependencies, choose Manage NuGet Packages and in Browse tab, search `Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions` and install the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error when I had both the 3.1.416 and 5.0.405 SDKs installed, on a project that targets 3.1. For some reason it built on the command line, but when I tried to debug using Visual Studio Code, I got the error.

I was able to fix it by creating a `global.json` in the project (or one of its parent directories), with:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.416",
    "rollForward": "disable"
  }
}
```